# Encountered end tag "tr" with no matching start tag. Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code/markup

```
@for (int m = 0; m < Model.Parts.Count; m++ ) {
    var item2 = Model.Parts[m];
    <tr id='@item2.WorkOrderPartId'>
        <td></td>
        <td style='text-align:center'> @item2.LineNo </td>
        <td> @item2.SalesOrderLineNo</td> 
        <td style='text-align:center'>
            @item2.Length
        </td> 
        <td style='width:100px;text-align:right'>
          </td> 
        <td style='width:100px;text-align:left'>
         </td>
         </td>
        <td style='padding-right:10px'>0</td>
        <td style='padding-right:10px'>0</td> 
    <td class='RemainingWeight'></td>
    <td>  </td> 
        </tr>
}
```

When this view get executed following error is getting OnException.

> Encountered end tag "tr" with no matching start tag.  Are your
>   start/end tags properly balanced?

Please helpme? :(

Comment: Extra closing td tag in your code </td>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good indentation is the key to success.

```
@for (int m = 0; m < Model.Parts.Count; m++ ) {
    var item2 = Model.Parts[m];
    <tr id='@item2.WorkOrderPartId'>
        <td></td>
        <td style='text-align:center'> @item2.LineNo </td>
        <td> @item2.SalesOrderLineNo</td> 
        <td style='text-align:center'>
            @item2.Length
        </td> 
        <td style='width:100px;text-align:right'></td> 
        <td style='width:100px;text-align:left'></td>
        <td style='padding-right:10px'>0</td>
        <td style='padding-right:10px'>0</td> 
        <td class='RemainingWeight'></td>
        <td></td> 
    </tr>
}
```

You had

```
<td style='width:100px;text-align:left'>
         </td>
         </td>
```

Which should just be

```
 <td style='width:100px;text-align:left'></td>
```

Comment: Also check for wrong self closing tags. My html structure was correct but I had an <a> element that I did as self closing by mistake which threw the html structure off. `<a href="" />` instead of `<a href=""></a>`

Answer (score 2):

In case of this code block only You have one extra td end tag that is:

```
<td style='width:100px;text-align:left'>
         </td>
         </td>
```

... Athough to detect in future If you are using visual studio then click on the starting tag of a  it will highlight the corresponding end Tag. If it doesn't highlight an end tag for one of the starting tag then that one is missing the end tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional  end tag without a start tag for the same in the code you have shared. The one marked in ** below from your code snippet.

```
<td style='width:100px;text-align:left'>
     </td>
     **</td>**
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure is this solve your problem.

Anyway you can just try this code.

```
@for (int m = 0; m < Model.Parts.Count; m++)
{
    var item2 = Model.Parts[m];
    <tr id='@item2.WorkOrderPartId'>
        <td></td>
        <td style='text-align:center'> @item2.LineNo </td>
        <td> @item2.SalesOrderLineNo</td>
        <td style='text-align:center'>
            @item2.Length
        </td>
        <td style='width:100px;text-align:right'></td>
        <td style='width:100px;text-align:left'></td>
        <td style='padding-right:10px'>0</td>
        <td style='padding-right:10px'>0</td>
        <td class='RemainingWeight'></td>
        <td>  </td>
    </tr>
}
```

There was an extra **closing td** tag in your code.